# Remove CSS rule for Material UI component in theme overrides

Tags: css, material-ui

I want to remove the CSS padding-bottom in the Material UI CardContent component. But I only find solutions on setting it to something else. My current workaround is to set it to something invalid (e.g. -1) so browsers will just ignore it.

I have this theme which contains the workaround:

```js
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCardContent: {
      root: {
        "&:last-child": {
          paddingBottom: -1,
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

would would be the correct way of remove a css rule from a component in Material UI.
(I already tried `inherit`, `initial`, `revert` and `unset`). Setting it to `0` is not what I want because I want the padding of the MuiCardContent without `last-child` to get applied.

Comment: [Setting it to 0 is not what I want because I want the padding of the MuiCardContent without last-child to get applied.]
Can you clarify this? I think setting it to 0 will preserve padding of non last-child card content.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-saha-zvwqi?file=/src/App.tsx
And I have no problem.

Comment: No, in your example you end with no padding and the last two card items, the result I want is like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-shannon-xbonr?file=/src/App.tsx but the -1 will show as invalid value in e.g. Chrome